# Pandas - Resample when not multiple of frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I have a time-serie on daily frequency across 1204 days.
I want to resample it on a 365D basis (by summing) but the time-serie runs across 3,29 * 365D, not a multiple of 365D.
By default, resample is returning 4 lines.

Here is the raw data:

```
DATE
2012-08-12    15350.0
2012-08-19    11204.0
2012-08-26    11795.0
2012-09-02    15160.0
2012-09-09     9991.0
2012-09-16    12337.0
2012-09-23    10721.0
2012-09-30     9952.0
2012-10-07    11903.0
2012-10-14     8537.0
               ...   
2015-09-27    14234.0
2015-10-04    17917.0
2015-10-11    13610.0
2015-10-18     8716.0
2015-10-25    15191.0
2015-11-01     8925.0
2015-11-08    13306.0
2015-11-15     8884.0
2015-11-22    11527.0
2015-11-29     6859.0

df.index.max() - df.index.min()
Timedelta('1204 days 00:00:00')
```

If I apply:

```
df.resample('365D').sum()
```

I got:

```
DATE
2012-08-12    536310.0
2013-08-12    555016.0
2014-08-12    569548.0
2015-08-12    245942.0
Freq: 365D, dtype: float64
```

It seems like the last bin is the one covering less than 365 days.
How do I force resample to exclude it from the result?

Comment: can you put here some example data of yours?

Comment: please add some code snippet and sample data.

Comment: @tworec : example added, thanks

Comment: @Mr.A : done, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.resample('365D')` starts sampling at lowest day in index. So last bin will be almost allways not covering all days. Just skip it

```
df.resample('365D').sum()[:-1]
```

You can also consider sampling by start/end of the year

```
df.resample('A').sum()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I make the sample finishing on the highest day so that the full bins are the most recent ones ? And then skip the first bin.

Comment: everything is possible. :) To use highest day you must to add artificial date to your index that is befor lowest date and have same month and day as highest date  `df[df.index[-1] + pd.DateOffset(year=df.index[0].year-1) + pd.Timedelta('2D')]=0`

Comment: be ware! sampling by 365D brokes down for leap years

Comment: upvoted! how does this work if my data keeps changing, i have a similar case where i need complete 30 min candles from 15 min candles, i keep fetching new data so at point A, i have candles for 12:00 12:15 12:30 where 12:15 and 12:30 make my candle for 12:30 i want to skip 12:15 here but  at point B i have 12:15 12:30 12:45 and no rows should be skipped, applies to other timeframes as well like 1H etc, only concerned about partial bins at the start

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272670/pandas-0-22-resample-only-full-bins-drop-partials