# pandas 0.22, resample only full bins, drop partials

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resample 1h bins of trading data into 4h bins.
The problem is that my pandas code gives also output of partial bins that are not closed yet.

My Input:

```
                  close    high     low    open  symbol       turnover  \
timestamp
2018-05-08 03:00:00  9418.0  9449.0  9408.5  9412.5  XBTUSD  1091577940325
2018-05-08 04:00:00  9423.5  9435.0  9390.0  9418.0  XBTUSD   801492831858
2018-05-08 05:00:00  9414.0  9428.5  9393.5  9423.5  XBTUSD   445420257388
2018-05-08 06:00:00  9337.0  9414.0  9314.5  9414.0  XBTUSD  1349710247828
2018-05-08 07:00:00  9328.5  9359.5  9305.0  9337.0  XBTUSD  1103092129997
2018-05-08 08:00:00  9355.0  9359.5  9328.5  9328.5  XBTUSD   647813850343
2018-05-08 09:00:00  9376.0  9383.0  9355.0  9355.0  XBTUSD   597066647876
2018-05-08 10:00:00  9312.0  9376.5  9241.5  9376.0  XBTUSD  1933554301163
2018-05-08 11:00:00  9296.0  9338.0  9275.5  9312.0  XBTUSD  1318169059747
2018-05-08 12:00:00  9201.5  9305.0  9178.0  9296.0  XBTUSD  2058057970783
```

My Output:

```
                   open    high     low   close     volume         vwap  \
timestamp
2018-05-08 04:00:00  9418.0  9435.0  9305.0  9328.5  346736372  9380.972675
2018-05-08 08:00:00  9328.5  9383.0  9241.5  9296.0  419074812  9332.798550
2018-05-08 12:00:00  9296.0  9305.0  9178.0  9201.5  189922434  9228.497600
```

Note that the 4h interval from 12:00 till 16:00 contains the partial data from the 12:00 hourly interval of the source.

My Desired output should look like:

```
                     open    high     low   close     volume         vwap  \
timestamp
2018-05-08 04:00:00  9418.0  9435.0  9305.0  9328.5  346736372  9380.972675
2018-05-08 08:00:00  9328.5  9383.0  9241.5  9296.0  419074812  9332.798550
```

So that only the whole 12:00 interval must be closed in order to give data in the resampling process.

My Code so far:

```
outputData = srcData.resample('4H').agg({'open': 'first',
                                                'high': 'max',
                                                'low': 'min',
                                                'close': 'last',
                                                'volume': 'sum',
                                                'vwap': 'mean',
                                                'turnover': 'sum',
                                                'symbol': 'first'})
```

Is there a function in pandas that would help me or do I have to figure out a way to cut the partial interval off after resampling?
Cheers
Alex

Comment: On way to do this to add an count in  your agg method and then eliminate all resulting records where count is less than 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a count into your agg method then use that count column to filter the resulting dataframe to show only "full bins".

```
df_out = df.resample('4H').agg({'open': 'first',
                                 'high': 'max',
                                                 'low': 'min',
                                                 'close': 'last',
                                                 'turnover': 'sum',
                                                 'symbol': ['first','count']})
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('_'.join)

df_out.query('symbol_count == 4')
```

Output:

```
                     open_first  high_max  low_min  close_last   turnover_sum symbol_first  symbol_count
timestamp                                                                                               
2018-05-08 04:00:00      9418.0    9435.0   9305.0      9328.5  3699715467071       XBTUSD             4
2018-05-08 08:00:00      9328.5    9383.0   9241.5      9296.0  4496603859129       XBTUSD             4
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a good idea. I dropped the join part and query for outputData = outputData[outputData.symbol['count'] == 4] instead.